# Where do they get $2+(8\times 2)$ in this counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtom2.png)

The question is how many ways i can line up the class so $2$ of it(Donald and marco, colored blues) aren’t adjacent to each other using multiplication and substraction principle.
So the answer is :
Ways to put Donald and marco in the line in adjacent places:
$$2 + (8 \times 2) = 18$$
Ways of lining up the class so the two boys are adjacent:
$$18 \times 8!$$
Ways so the two aren’t adjacent:
$$10! – (18 \times 8!)$$

Here is the problem, I don’t understand the first step of it, how to get $$2  + (8 \times 2) = 18$$ ?

Comment: Don't call something a probability question when probability is not mentioned.  This is a counting problem, a combinatorics problem... not a probability problem.  Maybe if you were to extend the question to ask "*what is the probability that these two students don't sit next to one another*" you could make it one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore how they have written it.  I agree, it doesn't look good.

Pick whether Marco comes before Donald or vice versa: $2$ options.

Whoever was picked to come first... pick which of the nine available positions they are placed (*noting that the tenth position is not allowed since that would violate the condition that they came before the other, there is nowhere for the other to go after them at that point*).

There are $2\times 9 = 18$ ways for the two of them to be placed adjacent to one another (*before considering how any of the other people are placed*).

---

If we wanted to force the result to look like theirs...

Pick which seat Marco sits in.  There are $10$ choices.  Of those ten choices, two are at the ends.  If Marco sits at one of the ends, then there is only one choice as to where Donald could sit if he were to sit next to Marco.

For the remaining eight options of where Marco could sit, there are two open seats available for Donald to sit.